Why can't my QFieldSync project not be converted into the export directory?
I'm running the latest update of QFieldSync plugin (version 4.10.1) in QGIS 3.34.7
After packaging my project and all the layers for QField I sync it with QFieldCloud using QFieldSync the way I've always done it before the update as follows.

Opening the QFieldCloud Projects Overview
Click "Create New Project"
Select "Create New Project: Convert currently open project to cloud project (recommended)" and click "Next"
Sssign it to the correct organization in the drop-down list.
Browse and select the local mirror directory (an empty folder within my project folder)
Click 'OK' on the pop-up dialog: "The entered path does not contain a QGIS project file yet. You can always add one later." (Clicking 'Create' used to make a new project file in the local mirror directory, so this was always fine.)
Click 'Create'

This is the exact same as before the update, only now get this error
2024-08-13T19:14:20     CRITICAL    The project could not be converted into the export directory.

I also encountered the same error as you. I did the following:

Uninstall QField installed in QGIS.
Restart the laptop.
Go to the page: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qfieldsync/version/v4.9.1/ download version 4.9.1 as *.zip
Install QField with zip file.
I did it


I had the same problem as the OP and this solution worked for me, except I didn't have to restart my computer. I just downloaded that version of the plugin and installed in the plugins/manage and install plugins/install from zip
